# how to extract rar on current path linux?

Tags: php, linux

i have a different archive files like `.zip,.tar,.tar.gz,.tgz,.rar` to extract, already i have done the scripts(PHP) for extract all types expect one `.rar`, i tried the below one, but it's not working

```
<?php
$rar_file = rar_open('example.rar') or die("Can't open Rar archive");
$entries = rar_list($rar_file); 
foreach ($entries as $entry) { 
    echo 'Filename: ' . $entry->getName() . "\n"; 
    $entry->extract('./uploaded_files/files/');
} 
rar_close($rar_file); 
?>
```

please suggest any ideas, thanks

Comment: Elaborate on "it's not working". Did you read the php docs?

Comment: it throws error `Tue Dec 23 12:18:20.514031 2014] [:error] [pid 6840] [client 192.168.71.57:50721] PHP Fatal error:  Call to undefined function rar_open() in /var/www/html/multi_upload/rar.php on line 2`

Answer (score 2):

**To install PHP rar module follow below steps.**

Rar is currently available through PECL » http://pecl.php.net/package/rar.

Also you can use the PECL installer to install the Rar extension, using the following command: pecl -v install rar.

You can always download the tar.gz package and install Rar by hand:

**Example #1 Rar installation**

```
gunzip rar-xxx.tgz
tar -xvf rar-xxx.tar
cd rar-xxx
phpize
./configure && make && make install
```

Comment: Restart webserver? **sudo service apache2 restart**

Comment: ya, `service httpd restart`

Comment: try **php -m** and check for rar module?

Answer (score 1):

Chances are you do not have the [PECL rar](http://php.net/manual/en/rar.installation.php) package installed, try installing it, restart web service (apache or nginx) and try again.

Comment: So when you type `php -m` from the command line you see rar as an installed module?

Comment: there is no rar but it shows already installed when in try `yum install rar`

Comment: **yum install rar** will install system package not php module.